# Firewall Based on NIC

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, firewall

I have an IIS 8.5 Server running on Windows Server 2012 r2.

The server itself has 2 network cards.

Rewrite:

Can you block ports based on a network adapter? 
IE: I have two network adapters, both are connected to the same network. 
I want to block all ports (but one) on one adapter,  on the other adapter i would like to have different ports blocked... 
So far it seems you can only have one over network access firewall rule.

Comment: ISS on Server 2013?

Comment: Does "set it up right instead of trying to use a janky dual-homing solution" count as a tip?  Because really, that's what you should be doing.  Put your network behind a proper firewall, then control external access to the webserver on the network's firewall, instead of what you're doing here.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question.  What do you mean by have one network card access the outside network and one the internal.  Are you saying you want your IIS server to act as a firewall?

Comment: I rewrote it to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work, as "access the internet" means default gateway, and you can only have one of those.

What I recommend you to do is forwarding the port from the Firewall (internal-gateway) to your Webserver. This is the cleanest way.